# Is There any way to get current location without using the CLLocationManager delegates in my application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, geolocation, cllocationmanager

I want to provide one method in my library that returns the current location.But I am not able to do that, because location will update and get in CLLocationManager delegate methods.So is there is any way to return back user with location after calling a method in my library.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `block` parameter to your library method that will be called when it receives a location update. That block can then be saved in a property (or into an array if multiple objects could be waiting at the same time).

p.s. You really should use `CLLocationManager`. Any other method of determining the location will be less accurate / just as (if not more) time consuming.

---

You can define a block like (depending on how many locations you want to pass):

```
typedef void(^LocationUpdateBlock)(CLLocation *location);
```

Then you add a public interface for the interested classes to register (simple version):

```
property (copy, nonatomic) LocationUpdateBlock locationUpdateBlock;
```

Then in your delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if (self.locationUpdateBlock != nil) {
        self.locationUpdateBlock([locations lastObject]);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Also, bypassing `CLLocationManager` will bypass the built-in location gathering permissions process, and per §4.1 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), "Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected." Like you say, using `CLLocationManager` and providing an API that employ completion blocks that are called asynchronously is the way to go.

Comment: @Rob even if a library uses `CLLocationManager`, the user will still get the permission dialog. It is totally fine and a violation of any guideline. It would be a really big privacy hole if that were actually possible.

Comment: @St3fan Sorry, I wasn't clear. That was precisely my point, that you want to use `CLLocationManager` so you get that confirmation. I was simply trying to provide another reason why Wain's suggestion of using `CLLocationManager`, rather than trying to bypass it, is a good idea.

Comment: @Wain sorry I didn't get your solution, can you explain me in deatails, how the block will come here with some sample code.